# Do spaceship weapons in Star Wars have a maximum range?

Tags: star-wars

Spaceships in *Star Wars* frequently use energy weapons for combat. Given that [Sir Isaac Newton is the deadliest SOB in space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCoHT_cHPzY), I was wondering if this also applies to the non-kinetic space weapons used in *Star Wars*. Do they have a maximum range after which the shot dissipates, or do they veer off into deep space and possibly hit some unlucky sod several millennia later?

Comment: Related, not a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20200/what-is-the-maximum-effective-range-of-the-death-stars-superlaser?rq=1

Comment: Very significant: https://xkcd.com/1433/

Comment: Max range: Whenever it hits something.

Comment: That depends... if you are a storm trooper your maximum effective range with a blaster is about 4 inches.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in canon, the weapons have a maximum range. As demonstrated in [this discussion](http://www.st-v-sw.net/STSW-WeaponRange-Wars.html) talking about some of the dialog from the first movie, *A New Hope*, Han makes the comment that the TIE fighter is "almost in range" as they pursue it towards what they later discover is the *Death Star*. It's clear from the view through the cockpit that the range is fairly short for the weapons the *Millennium Falcon* was carrying. If you go by the math in the discussion, the TIE fighter was only about 300 meters ahead of the *Falcon*, making it a very short distance.

The next movie, *The Empire Strikes Back*, also makes it clear that the weapons from a capital ship like a star destroyer have a much greater range. The discussion on the same page as above discusses a sequence where two destroyers are coming at the *Falcon*. From their math, a maximum weapons range is at least 75 kilometers, possibly over 135 km, though an effective range would be much less against a small, fast moving target like the *Falcon*.

From the same movie, it is clear that a ground based energy weapon can have a much greater range and effectiveness, as the rebel ion cannon fires from their ground base and disables star destroyers in orbit around Hoth. Even a conservative estimate of how high those star destroyers would be orbiting would place that range at greater than 1000 kilometers if they were in a fairly low orbit around the planet. A more likely figure would be closer to 5000 km from the ground to their positions.

So, yes, from canon we can determine that energy weapons have a maximum range, and that the range varies based on the source of the weapon.

As a side note in comparison, in the X-Wing series of video games (which was of dubious canon state even before the Legends), the maximum range for energy weapons from fighters and small freighters like the *Falcon* is 1.5 kilometers distance, at which point their energy has dissipated enough to no longer be viable.

Comment: Those games were awesome.

Answer (score 0):

All beams over a given distance will lose focus.  While the advanced technology may allow that to be a very large distance, there would still be a physical limitation as quantum mechanics will stop the physical device from being able to focus past a certain point.  So like a magnifying glass the non-kinetic weapons need a strong focal point.  You usually cannot set alight unless you have a very narrow beam.

Additionally while space is usually considered empty this is only mostly true and over a distance the beam would deteriorate interacting with radiation and background particles.

This means that the non-kinetic will keep going until it hits but will slowly disperse to have a weaker and weaker effect over a large enough distance.  So while there is no actual hard limit range, you could probably apply an 'effective' range to these types of weapons.

Note:  This question is based mostly of my understanding of physics and am unaware of any in-universe factors that would change this answer.

Comment: I am looking for an in-universe answer, not one based on our limited grasp on how space lasers work.