# From how far away can Force Choke be used?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Darth Vader uses Force Choke to kill Admiral Ozzel. At the time Vader is in his meditation chamber while Ozzel and Needa are presumably on the bridge of the Executor.

I can't find an exact map of [The Executor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Executor) but it's implied here that Vader is using Force Choke from a distance.

From how far away can he Force Choke a victim?

Comment: The ability Force Choke has a 10m range and requires line of sight in Star Wars: The Old Republic. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

It can be used across thousands of light years. In the recently launched episode [S06E10](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-lost-one-episode-guide) of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars (The Lost Missions)*, Palpatine (who was on Coruscant) choked Count Dooku (who was in his HQ) from thousands of light years away*.

I don't have canon backup, but its possible that force choke could be triggered via communication channel. Or, its just unexplainable for force telekinesis.

*I am still trying to find distance between Coruscant and Raxus Prime. If you know it, please update the answer.

Comment: I estimate Raxus to be around 31,000 light years from Coruscant. This is assuming [Kiribi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kiribi) is around 5,000 light years away from Coruscant. I measured the ratios of Kibiri and Raxus' distances from Coruscant from the Atlas (which I think is canon?).

Comment: Perhaps it's a line-of-sight thing, even over video screens. "If I can see you, I can choke you."

Comment: @Alizter:  I don't know which Altas you're referring to because I'm not an expert (a link or image would be nice), but I doubt you can get an accurate estimate like this since presumable the Atlas is projecting a set of 3D positions onto a plane.

Comment: @ThePopMachine It was from the Star Wars Atlas, the galaxy is relatively flat so order of magnitudes wise it should be a close estimate.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the person choking the victim will need to be close to the victim if he/she wants to force choke without looking at the victim.

As shown in this example.

'***Some individuals were also powerful enough and experienced enough to not require any visuals to kill someone via force choke***, such as when Letta Turmond's Jedi backer, later revealed to be Barriss Offee, killed her via a force choke and subsequently framed Ahsoka Tano for the deed.

As well as when Darth Sidious used the ability to ***kill the Shadow Collective guards standing near the door before opening it to confront his former apprentice***, Darth Maul and the latter's apprentice, Savage Oppress.

With visuals it seems they can choke the victim from a long distance away.

***ESPECIALLY -*** Darth Vader was also seen using this ability to express his dissatisfaction with an Imperial officer during one of his Jedi hunts, choking the man while staring pointedly away from him.'

Sorry, the link is here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Telekinesis

Comment: What are these quotes from?

Comment: Wookiepedia - Star Wars!

Comment: The crux of the question is really about the distance, not so much about whether or not visuals are required.

Comment: For future reference, when quoting another source on the internet it is good taste to include a link to said source.

Comment: This indeed regards to distance. By this statement, we can assume that force choke can be performed as far as a visual communication can be established

Comment: It seems to me that the ability to kill anyone throughout the galaxy just by thinking of them is a little OP.

Answer (score 3):

In the canon *Skywalker Strikes* comic book, Vader is contacted by an Imperial officer while he is one the planet Cymoon 1. The officer was on a Star Destroyer, and was not visible, but Vader managed to choke him anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In "Outbound Flight", a (spoilers hidden) "Jedi turned to the Dark Side" chokes his opponent commander who is on his command ship at an unspecified distance - but within visual range for a large battle with multi-minute flight ranges for fighter ships. I believe just before this time they were exchanging bad words over a comlink, and the Jedi held his choking grip for minutes until an unplanned usage of weaponry intended elsewhere had his ship practically destroyed.

Comment: can he actually see the commander, or can he only see the ship?

Comment: There was a sudden hiss from the comm. "So," an almost unrecognizable voice ground out. "You think you have won, alien?" The display came alive ......(snip).....  "You were told wrongly," (the fallen Jedi) countered. "The role of the Jedi is to lead and guide, and to destroy all threats." The unburned corner of his lip twisted upward in a bitter smile.
 And without warning, (Commander)'s head jerked back, his whole body pressing back against his seat. His hand darted to his throat, clutching uselessly at it.