# Did Vader's actions during the Battle of Yavin get him sent to The Empire's Court martial?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In *Star Wars IV: A New Hope*, after realizing that the Rebels were focused on a particular objective, Darth Vader, apparently without consulting his superior Grand Moff Tarkin - who incidentally kept pensive and silent - took two Wingmen and piloting an experimental modified early prototype of the starfighter TIE Advanced x1, diverted Tarkin's war plans and consequently made the Empire lose not only the Battle of Yavin but also the astronomically expensive Death Star. Did these actions get him tried and convicted in the Empire's court martial?

[image: Still picture from Star Wars: A New Hope (1977)]

Comment: He was summarily executed shortly thereafter.

Comment: You might as well ask if he got a poor performance review in the flight debriefing. Even if it happened, why would it matter? He's Darth Vader. And why do you hold Vader responsible for the loss of the battle? Is it canon that the Empire court martials people for simply failing? It also seems oddly arbitrary to ask about bureaucratic events for a movie and universe that is not at all focused on such things.

Comment: "It was known among Imperial officers that Darth Vader often simply did not bother with a court-martial when it came to discipline"
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Court-martial

Comment: ...he actually was about to save the Imperial day if it hadn't been for Han Solo...

Comment: @Palliser The context of that quote is that Darth Vader murders people who would normally be court-martialled. Not that he himself avoids court-martials.

Comment: @Harabeck - I believe the OP is trying to explain that Vader, as the only one who knew that the ability to destroy Yavin 4 using the Death Star was insignificant next to the power of a proton torpedo guided by the Force, was unable to prevent it from happening, so...he had to pay for it.

Comment: If only they’d made a sequel, we might have found out.

Comment: It's a bit over the top to say that Vader was responsible for the loss of the Death Star.  He was in fact the only one who realized the true danger. And the only one to attempt to stop it from happening, and was almost successful in doing so.

Comment: @JK At least one other office saw danger, as I recall, but Tarkin ignored his warnings.

Answer (score 4):

**He was punished in other ways.**

Firstly, I disagree with some of the points made in your question.

> Darth Vader, apparently without consulting his superior Grand Moff Tarkin

While Tarkin might have held a higher position than Vader [specifically on the Death Star](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/103903/51226), Vader's rank is nebulous enough that he didn't seem required to seek express permission from Tarkin to perform his normal duties.

> took two Wingmen and piloting an experimental modified early prototype of the starfighter TIE Advanced x1,

Given that it was *[his](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_TIE_Advanced)* TIE Advanced x1, I don't see why he'd get in trouble for using it. Similarly, the wingmen were from [his personal squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Squadron_(Galactic_Empire)), meaning they were his to direct.

> diverted Tarkin's war plans and consequently made the Empire lose not only the Battle of Yavin but also the astronomically expensive Death Star.

Tarkin grossly underestimated the Rebellion's capabilities. Without Vader and the ships under his command, the Rebels likely would have had a much easier job.

I would argue various parties held more blame for the Death Star's destruction than Vader. Various Imperials championed the project without accounting for its flaws. Krennic, who oversaw the station's construction, failed to realize chief engineer Erso's treachery or the weakness he implemented in time. Tarken, as mentioned, failed to properly defend the base or authorize a full evacuation.

Vader, due to his high position and lack of specific rank, was not subject to the same bureaucracy as other Imperials. In *From a Certain Point of View: The Empire Strikes Back*, a couple of officers discuss how it would ultimately be futile to report him for executing Ozzel.

However, despite all of these factors, the Emperor did place blame on Vader, as he was one of the sole survivors of the incident. However, it was because of his plan to intentionally let the *Falcon* escape, not for the reasons you mentioned. The 2015 *Darth Vader* comic series explores the consequences of his failure in detail.

> But you are the only one living to suffer my anger. You, an isolated survivor of the greatest military disaster in all my Empire's history? Oh, you are truly the Chosen One, Lord Vader. Chosen to be the one responsible - The Emperor, *Darth Vader 1*

His punishment was being put under the command of Cassio Tagge and being placed against various challengers to his position.

Answer (score 2):

The comic [Star Wars: Empire 14: The Savage Heart](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Empire_14:_The_Savage_Heart) tells the story of what happened to Vader after being flung from the Death Star I and his return to the Imperial Military.  As he arrives on Coruscant, he seems very much in charge and still in command.  The story doesn't delve into any Imperial after-action reports like we see Imperial Cadet Pilot Han Solo go through in the [deleted scene from Star Wars: Solo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TvzXPhzr4U).

Comment: It's worth noting that that's a Legends source.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the new *Star Wars* comics](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/19379/darth_vader_2015_-_2016) by Marvel/Disney from 2015, written by Kieron Gillen, Vader was punished by the Emperor. First, he was demoted and was subordinated to Admiral Tagge's command. Secondly, the cybernetics scientist Cylo was ordered by the Emperor to create replacers for Vader, which would take his place as the Emperor's right hand if they outdo Vader or kill him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Informal (if harsh) punishment from the Emperor isn't the same as a court martial, which is the subject of the question.  Note also that this is already discussed in the highest-voted answer.